# How to use on-mouse function in Racket?

Tags: racket

I am trying to make a text mover, which is the text will move to where I clicked. Also, when I press "left" key, I can change the color of the text. I think I finished each part the program needs, but I don't know how to put them together now :( I am still confused about how to use on-mouse function.
This is the position of the text part:

```
(require 2htdp/image)
(require 2htdp/universe)
(define POSN-0 (make-posn 50 50))
(define POSN-1 (make-posn 200 200))
(define POSN-2 (make-posn 100 100))
(define (posn-temp p)
  (... (posn-x p) ...
       (posn-y p) ...))
```

This is the color part:

```
(define Red "red")
(define Black "black")
(define Purple "purple")
(check-expect (RBP Red) "red")
(check-expect (RBP Black) "black")
(check-expect (RBP Purple) "purple")
(define (RBP c)
   (cond
     [(string=? c Red) "red"]
     [(string=? c Black) "black"]
     [(string=? c Purple) "purple"]))
```

This part provides all the information needed for the text-mover application, but I don't know how to use it？？

```
(define-struct tm [str pos col])
(define T1(make-tm "apple" 10  "red"))
(define T2(make-tm "banana" 20  "black"))
(define (tm-temp tm)
  (... (tm-str tm) ...
       (tm-pos tm) ...
       (tm-col tm) ...))
```

To-draw:

```
(define bg (square 400 "solid" "white"))

(check-expect
 (draw-tm POSN-0)
  (place-image
   (text "POG!"
   25
   "red")
    50 50
     bg))
(define (draw-tm c)
  (place-image
   (text "POG!"
   25
   (RBP c))
    50 50
     bg))
```

On-key:

```
(define (change-c c ke)
      (cond
        [(key=? ke "left") (RBP c)]
        [else c]))
```

On-mouse:

```
(define (move-tm c )
      (cond
        [(mouse=?  )   ]
        [else c]))
```

Big-bang:

```
(define (move-text initial-tm)
  (big-bang initial-tm
    [to-draw draw-tm]
    [on-mouse move-tm]
    [on-key change-c]))
```

Comment: Some issues with arguments to functions called by `big-bang`: typically they are called with a WorldState argument (maybe + other args). For a canvas which shows text at a position which can change, the WorldState needs to include the position. So eg `draw-tm`s argument is `tm`, not `c`, and it will use the position in `tm` to draw the text. `(define (move-tm tm x y me) ...` (see description of `on-mouse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [`on-mouse`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpuniverse.html#%28form._world._%28%28lib._2htdp%2Funiverse..rkt%29._on-mouse%29%29) description: function called with `on-mouse` has arguments `state x y event` and different types of mouse events are described in [Mouse event docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpuniverse.html#%28tech._world._mouseevent%29). In your case, you will need `"button-up"` or `"drag"`.

Also, when `x` or `y` or `color` changes, you have to create new instance of struct which represents state, using data from old instance.

Here is example code- run it with `(move-text "FooBar")`, you can drag displayed text into new position or change color with `left` key.

```
(require 2htdp/image)
(require 2htdp/universe)

(define-struct text-state [text position color])

(define (next-color color)
  (second (assoc color (list (list "black" "red")
                             (list "red" "purple")
                             (list "purple" "black")))))

(define bg (square 400 "solid" "white"))

(define (draw-state state)
  (place-image
   (text (text-state-text state)
         25
         (text-state-color state))
   (posn-x (text-state-position state))
   (posn-y (text-state-position state))
   bg))

(define (change-color state key)
  (if (key=? key "left")
      (make-text-state (text-state-text state)
                       (text-state-position state)
                       (next-color (text-state-color state)))
      state))

(define (mouse-fn state x y event)
  (if (string=? "drag" event)
      (make-text-state
       (text-state-text state)
       (make-posn x y)
       (text-state-color state))
      state))

(define (move-text text)
  (big-bang (make-text-state text (make-posn 50 50) "black")
    [to-draw draw-state]
    [on-mouse mouse-fn]
    [on-key change-color]))
```

Comment: Is it possible that the position of the text can move to the position of the mouse? Like after you click, the test move.  I know in java the position of mouse would be mouse-x and mouse-y, but what is it like in Racket. Can I just use the position of mouse to be the position of text? It also will provide an initial position.

Comment: I looked at the documentation. In this case,  can I use button-up and button-down in mouse event? When user push a mouse button, the text move.